# In odoo development, when I create data every time, there will be xml coding errors like this

Tags: python, xml, utf-8, lxml, odoo

I have created the model object and the corresponding xml, but when I click the Create button on the odoo front page to add a data object, the following error occurs:

> ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters

### System Specs:

- Ubuntu16.04. 2
- Odoo version is 10.0
- The python interpreter is 2.7
- lxml version is 3.5.0
- pycharm version is 2018
- chrome version is  50.0.2661.102 (64-bit)

when sudo locale，appear these 
LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=zh_CN:en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_TIME=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="zh_CN.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_NAME=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=zh_CN.UTF-8
LC_ALL=

### Code:

#### follower.py

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import models, api, fields
class follower(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    bug_ids = fields.Many2many('bm.bug',string='bug')
```

#### bugs.py

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import models,api,fields
class bug(models.Model):
    _name = 'bm.bug'
    _description = 'bug'
    name = fields.Char(u'bug简述',required=True)
    detail = fields.Text(size=150)
    is_closed = fields.Boolean(u'是否关闭')
    close_reason = fields.Selection([('changed',u'已修改'),('cannot',u'无法修改'),('delay',u'推迟')],string='关闭理由')
    user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users',string=u'负责人')
    follower_id = fields.Many2many('res.partner',string=u'关注者')
    @api.multi
    def do_close(self):
        for item in self:
            item.is_closed = True
        return True
```

#### bug_adv.py

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import api,fields,models
class bugAdvanced(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'bm.bug'
    need_time = fields.Integer(string='所需时间(小时)')
    name = fields.Char(help='简要描述发现的bug')
    stage_id = fields.Many2one('bm.bug.stage', string='阶段')
    tag_ids = fields.Many2many('bm.bug.tag',string='标示')
```

#### bug_stage.py

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import models,fields,api
class bugStage(models.Model):
    _name = 'bm.bug.stage'
    _description = 'bug阶段'
    _order = 'sequence,name'
    name = fields.Char('名称')
    desc_detail = fields.Text('描述')
    status = fields.Selection([('waiting','未开始'),('doing','进行中'),('closed','关闭'),('rework','重测未通过')],'状态')
    document = fields.Html('文档')
    sequence = fields.Integer('Sequence')
    percent_pro = fields.Float('进度',(3,2))
    deadline = fields.Date('最晚解决日期')
    create_on = fields.Datetime('创建时间',default=lambda self:fields.Datetime.now())
    delay = fields.Boolean('是否延误')
    image = fields.Binary('图片')
```

#### bug_tag.py

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import fields,models,api
class bugTag(models.Model):
    _name = 'bm.bug.tag'
    _description = 'bug标示'
    name = fields.Char('名称')
    bug_ids = fields.Many2many('bm.bug',string='bug')
```

#### bugs.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="bug-manage_list">
            <field name="name">bug列表</field>
            <field name="model">bm.bug</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree>
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="is_closed"/>
                    <field name="user_id"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="bug-manage_form">
            <field name="name">bug列表</field>
            <field name="model">bm.bug</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form>
                    <header>
                        <button name="do_close" type="object" string="关闭bug"/>
                    </header>
                    <sheet>
                        <group name="group_top" col="2">
                            <group name="goup_left">
                                <field name="name"/>
                                <field name="user_id"/>
                                <field name="is_closed"/>
                            </group>
                            <group name="group_right">
                                <field name="close_reason"/>
                                <field name="follower_id"/>
                            </group>
                        </group>
                        <notebook>
                            <page string="详细内容">
                                <field name="detail"/>
                            </page>
                        </notebook>
                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="bug-manage_search">
            <field name="name">bug搜索</field>
            <field name="model">bm.bug</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <search>
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="is_closed"/>
                    <field name="user_id"/>
                </search>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="bug-manage_action_window">
            <field name="name">bug-manage window</field>
            <field name="res_model">bm.bug</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        </record>>

        <menuitem name="bug管理系统" id="menu_root"/>
        <menuitem name="bug管 理" id="menu_1" parent="bug-manage.menu_root"/>
        <menuitem name="bug列表" id="menu_1_list" parent="bug-manage.menu_1" action="bug-manage.bug-manage_action_window"/>
    </data>>
</odoo>
```

#### follower.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="bug-manage_follower_form">
            <field name="name">关注者</field>
            <field name="model">res.partner</field>
base.view_partner_form-->
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="mobile" position="after">
                    <field name="bug_ids"/>
                </field>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="bug-manage_follower_action_window">
            <field name="name">follower window</field>
            <field name="res_model">res.partner</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        </record>

        <menuitem name="关注者管理" id="menu_2" parent="bug-manage.menu_root"/>
        <menuitem name="关注者" id="menu_2_form" parent="bug-manage.menu_2" action="bug-manage.bug-manage_follower_action_window"/>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

#### bugs_adv.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="bug-manage_form2">
            <field name="name">bug表单2</field>
            <field name="model">bm.bug</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="bug-manage.bug-manage_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='follower_id']" position="after">
                    <field name="stage_id"/>
                    <field name="tag_ids"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

### Error

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/python/Desktop/odoo10/server/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/python/Desktop/odoo10/server/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/python/Desktop/odoo10/server/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/python/Desktop/odoo10/server/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/python/Desktop/odoo10/server/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/python/Desktop/odoo10/server/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/python/Desktop/odoo10/server/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/python/Desktop/odoo10/server/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 872, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/python/Desktop/odoo10/server/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 864, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/python/Desktop/odoo10/server/odoo/api.py", line 685, in call_kw
    return call_kw_model(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/python/Desktop/odoo10/server/odoo/api.py", line 670, in call_kw_model
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/python/Desktop/odoo10/server/odoo/models.py", line 1328, in load_views
    for [v_id, v_type] in views
  File "/home/python/Desktop/odoo10/server/odoo/models.py", line 1328, in <dictcomp>
    for [v_id, v_type] in views
  File "/home/python/Desktop/odoo10/server/odoo/models.py", line 1399, in fields_view_get
    arch_etree = getattr(self, '_get_default_%s_view' % view_type)()
  File "/home/python/Desktop/odoo10/server/odoo/models.py", line 1230, in _get_default_tree_view
    return E.tree(element, string=self._description)
  File "/home/python/.virtualenvs/rhc_odoo_v10.0/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/builder.py", line 218, in __call__
    get(dict)(elem, attrib)
  File "/home/python/.virtualenvs/rhc_odoo_v10.0/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/builder.py", line 203, in add_dict
    attrib[k] = v
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 2402, in lxml.etree._Attrib.__setitem__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:72066)
  File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 570, in lxml.etree._setAttributeValue (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:23009)
  File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 1439, in lxml.etree._utf8 (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:32441)
ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters
```

Comment: Any chance you can switch to Python 3? The loose distinction between byte strings and Unicode strings in Python 2 can be a real pain and very hard to debug.

Comment: Thank you @lenz.I agree with you, but odoo10 now supports the python2 interpreter instead of python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make all your labels and specially `selection labels` and `help attributes` a **Unicode**  by using `u'your_label'`:

```
 help=u'简要描述发现的bug'

 _description = u'bug阶段'

string=u'所需时间(小时)'

fields.Selection([('waiting',u'未开始'),('doing',u'进行中')....
```

I'm coding in Arabic too, and I always use Unicode for my labels to avoid this problem.

Comment: Thank you @ElegantOdoo very much!You're so awesome.I have solved this problem by your method.

Comment: If my answer helped you, consider to accept it, I still have problem like this when If forget to put Unicode symbol.

Comment: There is another method to solve the problem. I didn't define a list view in my xml file for my bug_tag.py file. I showed the data of this model class in the front end, and odoo10 will be displayed in the form of a list by default. If I define the list view of this model class by myself in xml, I can run it well even if I don't add the ‘u’

Comment: Yes Odoo was bulding a tree view for you model and it used the description attribute to give the name of tree:  `E.tree(element, string=self._description)` and here the problem happened. because description was not Unicode. but I think you should use always `u''` sometime debugging this will be very difficult.